# Java: Rollback Database updates?

Tags: java, mysql, database, transactions

I have three methods that, together, save a node to the database. Currently, this does not achieve the desired effect of not committing the changes unless all the writes are successful.

```
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    writeNodeTable(node, newNodeNID);
    writeContentTypeBoutTable(node, newNodeNID);
    writeTerms(node, newNodeNID);
    conn.commit();
```

If there is a problem (such as an uncaught exception is thrown) in the second or third method, I'd like to roll back all the changes. Is there some way I can use transactions to do this?

This is one such DB writing function:

```
private void writeTerms(DrupalNode node, int newNodeNID) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO term_node (nid, vid, tid) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    prep.setInt(1, newNodeNID);
    prep.setInt(2, newNodeNID);

    String schoolName = termHelp.schoolOfAgainst(node.get(BoutField.against));
    prep.setString(3, schoolName);

    prep.execute();

    String fencerName = termHelp.fencerOfAgainst(node.get(BoutField.against));
    prep.setString(3, fencerName);
    prep.execute();
    prep.close();
}
```

Comment: Where is the Connection coming from in the three methods? It must be the same one that you started the transaction in (by turning off auto-commit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rollback` method in `Connection` interface.
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#rollback()

Also you have to set `setAutoCommit` to `false` and call `commit` and `rollback` methods as appropriately.

Comment: +1. Maybe you need to stress the need to "commit" more. Otherwise nothing will be saved in the DB, even if there is no "rollback".

Comment: Wouldn't work, unless you use same connection object. No negative cast, however. The answer still provides a little insight.

Comment: @Vinegar: Yes, one would need to use the same connection object (and also not commit in any of the three methods themselves).

Answer (score 5):

Upul is correct, you would need to implement the `Connection.setAutoCommit(false)` and the `Connection.rollback()` methods. One thing you might want to try for each transaction is to have this sort of flow:

```
Connection conn = null; // or have the connection sent in
try {
    conn = getConnection(username, password);
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    // do stuff with connection
    conn.commit();
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
    // handle error appropriately
    conn.rollback();
} finally {
    // cleanup
    conn.close(); // depends on when the connection was allocated
}
```

Comment: If the first got commit, you will no more be able to rollback when exception occur in the second or third.

Comment: @Vinegar the idea is to not do any commits until everything has been processed. I probably should have added that all three calls should have been executed in the do stuff with connection piece

Comment: You still says, "One thing you might want to try for **each transaction** is to have this sort of flow". Which is not gonna work.

Comment: @Vinegar, Maybe this is how I think of a transaction, but I imagine a transaction beginning when one allocates a database connection and a transaction ending when the connection object is committed or rolled back. So I'm imagining that all the changes [writeTable, writeContentTypeBoutTable, writeTerms] are happening between when the connection is first 'created' (depends on connection pooling strategy) and when the connection gets committed or rolled back.

Comment: And all 3 of those method should not have this sort of flow. Am I right? Those will just use the connection object to prepare the statement. Edited your post to revoke the negative, since **meanings** are much more important than **words**.

Comment: @Vinegar, Correct, this flow should executed from the caller of the three methods, which is similar to what you have suggested in your post.